# Proof of $\sum_{k=1}\cos^2\langle\vec{x},\vec{e}_{k}\rangle=1.$

Tags: geometry, analysis

I have serious difficulties proving that:

Let  $\vec{x},\vec{e}_{i}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ where $\vec{e}_{i}$ is the **basic unit vector** in $\mathbb{R}^n$ , $i=1,2,\ldots,n.$

Prove that 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\cos^{2}\langle\vec{x},\vec{e}_{k}\rangle=1.$$
Where $\langle\vec{x},\vec{e}_{k}\rangle$ is the **angle** between $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{e}_{i}.$

Answer (score 2):

Call $\;t_k\;$ the angle between $\;x\;$ and $\;e_k\;$ , and observe $\;\{e_1,...,e_n\}\;$ are an **orthonormal basis** of $\;\Bbb R^n\;$ , then

$$\cos t_k:=\frac{x\bullet e_k}{\left\|x\right\|\left\|e_k\right\|}=\frac{x\bullet e_k}{\left\|x\right\|}\implies$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\cos^2t_k=\frac1{\left\|x\right\|^2}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(x\bullet e_k\right)^2=\frac1{\left\|\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \left(x\bullet e_k\right)e_k\right\|^2} \sum_{k=1}^n \left(x\bullet e_k\right)^2=$$

$$=\frac1{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n(x\bullet e_k)^2}\sum_{k=1}^n (x\bullet e_k)^2=1$$

Comment: Other proof without using norms ?

Comment: The norm is just the square root of the inner (dot) product!: $\;\left\|x\right\|=(x\bullet x)^{1/2}\;$

Answer (score 1):

If $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^n$, the angle $\theta$ between $u$ and $v$ is given by (This can be proved using cosine law)
$$ \cos\theta = \frac{\langle u,v \rangle}{\lVert u \rVert\lVert v \rVert}
$$
where $\langle u,v \rangle$ is the **dot product**: (The superscript here indicates coordinates)
$$ \langle u,v \rangle = \sum_{k=1}^n u^k v^k
$$
Since $(e_k)_{k=1}^n$ are unit vectors, $\lVert e_k\rVert = 1$.($\lVert v \rVert^2 = \langle v,v \rangle$) Moreover, we can assume that $\lVert x \rVert = 1$. Therefore,
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{\langle x,e_k \rangle}{\lVert x \rVert\lVert e_k \rVert}\right)^2 = \sum_{k=1}^n \langle x,e_k \rangle^2 = \sum_{k=1}^n (x^k)^2 = \langle x, x \rangle = 1
$$

Answer (score 0):

$cos (x, e_i) = x_i /x$ so your equation is an n-dimensional Pythagorean theorem

$\sum x_i^2 / x^2 = 1$

If you really need to prove it,

$ (\sum x_i *e_i) = x$

$ <\sum x_i * e_i,  \sum x_i * e_i> = <x, x>$

$ \sum x_i^2 <e_i, e_i> + \sum_{i \ne j} x_i x_j <e_i,e_j> = x^2$
 Considering $<e_i, e_i> = 1$ and $<e_i, e_j>= 0$ you get your proof